# how to remove body onload function in java script?

Tags: javascript

I met one critical problem in java script .....help me to fix this.......

i have written the onload function in one jsp page say login.jsp...

in tat function i used window.open method to open a new window again with the same jsp page login.jsp with disabling the toolbars......

now wat happening is when iam opening same page again in new window obviously tat body onload function will again get called and opens a new window in indefinite........

but what i want is, i have to remove that onload function in tat jsp page once a new window is opened..

Is it possible to remove tat onload function while getting opened in the new window??

could anyone please come up with an idea or little bit of code to do this using java script??

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the same page a quick workaround could be to check if the *current* window has been opened programmatically, before executing `window.open`, something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  if (!window.opener) {
    window.open(/*...*/);
  }
};
```

The above code checks if the [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) property has a value.

This property contains a reference to the window that opened this *current window*, and of course if the current window hasn't been opened programmatically, it will contain `null`.

In conclusion, the `window.open` method will be invoked only once.

Comment: i couldnt get " check if the current window has been opened programmatically". I open this login.jsp thro URL.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: when you open the page manually (e.g. you type the address, click a hyperlink/bookmark to your page, etc...) the `window.opener` property is `null`, and the `window.open` method will be executed, opening the same page, but now this time (in the page you just opened through code) when the `onload` event fires there, the `window.opener` property will refer to the *"parent"* page, and it will not execute the `window.open` method again.

Comment: its working fine... 

wen i type the address in the url and click go.
the contents of tat jsp page is displaying in the tat (parent) window and then it goes to the new window(child window) where the toolbar is disabled....

but, i dont want any content of login.jsp to be displayed in the parent window(Wen url s clicked), want it only in the child window...

can u pls help me out...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're going about this the wrong way.

Although there may be a way to intercept the onload function before it actually runs (some javascript libraries can help you to add a handler to the OnDocumentReady event), but maybe you should be doing something serverside.  For example - If you want NOT to popup the window in the second window, then one way is to set a querystring parameter telling the server not to add that attribute to the body tag.

You could also check the referrer.  If the user is coming from that page, then don't add the attribute to the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the popup JSP look to see whether you're coming from the problematic page. If so, set `window.onload = null` -- better yet, don't set anything at all in that JSP.

Comment: IE sometimes ignore setting event handlers to null. Better set it to `function(){}`.